# Laravel 6 Database Seed problem: Table doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-6

I am designing a website which allows users to post, review and edit books. I am currently working on the roles of each user, and I have encounter a problem with the seeding to the user_role. I am being met with the error below, but can't figure out why.

Only assumption is that it is named role_user somewhere, but cant see where or why?

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dockerphp.role_user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (1, 1))

  at /srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dockerphp.role_user' doesn't exist")
      /srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:457

  2   PDO::prepare("insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (?, ?)")
      /srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:457
```

My seeders look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        User::truncate();
        DB::table('user_role')->truncate();

        $authorRole = Role::where('name', 'Author')->first();
        $editorRole = Role::where('name', 'Editor')->first();
        $readerRole = Role::where('name', 'Reader')->first();

        $Author = User::create([
            'name' => 'Test Author',
            'email' => 'Test@author.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('testtest')
        ]);

        $Editor = User::create([
            'name' => 'Test Editor',
            'email' => 'Test@editor.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('testtest')
        ]);

        $Reader = User::create([
            'name' => 'Test Reader',
            'email' => 'Test@reader.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('testtest')
        ]);

        $Author->roles()->attach($authorRole);
        $Editor->roles()->attach($editorRole);
        $Reader->roles()->attach($readerRole);
    }
}
```

The above one seems to be the one encountering the problem, as the below seeder worked perfectly fine.

```
class RolesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Role::truncate();
        Role::create(['name' => 'Author']);
        Role::create(['name' => 'Editor']);
        Role::create(['name' => 'Reader']);
    }
}
```

Finally, my database seeder looks like this:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

- Role model is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

And user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'about', 'avatar' 
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the table exist in the database?

Comment: The table is called user_role, like outlined in the code which is why I cant understand this error.

Comment: Are you using an external package for the roles? Default pivot table names are named alphabetically in Laravel, so `role_user` instead of `user_role`

Comment: You are trying to insert into a table name `role_user` not `user_role`.

Comment: But where in the code is there a role_user table being referenced it is always user_role, I have noticed that Alex Gholamian

Comment: You probably set up relations between your models, and as said, default pivot table names use alphabetically ordered names of the models in Laravel: `role_user`

Comment: I get what your saying now. Models have been added to the question. How can I make it so the relation is stored as user_role rather than role_user

Comment: From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many): "_However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the belongsToMany method_"

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help/

Answer (score 0):

Problem lied with Laravel naming the relation alphabetically, so rather it being stored as user_role, it was stored as role_user.
Was solved by changing in both models:
from

```
public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

to

```
public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role');
    }
```